# Quando clico no botão mais de 1 vez a contagem se acelera

Tags: javascript, onclick, countdown

Gente eu consegui de um amigo aqui do fórum um script de um botão com contagem regressiva, que ao clicar se inicia a contagem. Agradeço muito porque é muito bom... só tem um problema, quando clico mais de uma vez no botão a contagem regressiva se acelera, veja o código↓

```html
<script language="JavaScript">
  function dispara( span ) {
    conta( this, document.getElementById( span ) );
  }

  function conta( botao, contador ) {
    botao.disabled=true;
    if(contador.innerHTML==0) {
      contador.innerHTML = 10;
      botao.disabled=false;
      return false;
    }
    contador.innerHTML = contador.innerHTML - 1;
    setTimeout( function(){conta( botao, contador )}, 1000 );
  }
</script>

<input type="button" value="botao1" onclick="dispara('s1')" class="btn">
<span id="s1">10</span>
<br/><br/>
<input type="button" value="botao2" onclick="dispara('s2')" class="btn">
<span id="s2">10</span>
```

Poderiam me ajudar a resolver esse problema?

Comment: O `this` em `dispara` não é o botão (como a outra função espera), e é isso que está causando o problema.

Comment: Eu preciso do this, o this serve para pegar o botão clicado, dispensando seu ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bom, resolvi assim. Sei que não é a melhor forma possivel, mas é uma soluçao. Como disse o colega ai, ele noa esta pegando o botao com esse this. Entao coloquei o id do botao, é passado para a funcao, e esse id do botao coloquei o mesmo nome da classe do contador, assim o o que ele passa para a funcao é o id do botao e tbm  a classe do contador, assim posso encontrar os 2. Olha:

```
    <script language="JavaScript">
  function dispara( span ) {
    conta( span, document.getElementsByClassName( span )[0]);
  }

  function conta( botao, contador ) {

    document.getElementById(botao).disabled=true;
    if(contador.innerHTML==0) {
      contador.innerHTML = 10;
      document.getElementById(botao).disabled=false;

      return false;
    }
      contador.innerHTML = contador.innerHTML - 1;
    setTimeout( function(){conta( botao, contador )}, 1000 );
  }
</script>

<input type="button" value="botao1" onclick="dispara('s1')" id="s1" class="btn">
<span class="s1">10</span>
<br/><br/>
<input type="button" value="botao2" onclick="dispara('s2')" id="s2" class="btn">
<span class="s2">10</span>
```

Espero ter ajudado!!!

Comment: Ótimo! Só me tira uma duvida, eu posso no lugar de s1 colocar o nome que esta no value, pra não precisar ficar colocando s1, s2, s3. AI eu quero colocar assim:                                                                                   `<input type="button" value="botao1" onclick="dispara('botao1')" id="botao1" class="btn">
<span class="botao1">10</span>
<input type="button" value="botao2" onclick="dispara('botao2')" id="botao2" class="btn">
<span class="botao2">10</span>`

Comment: Pode, só lembre de colocar o mesmo id do botao na classe do contador...

Comment: Então valeu amigo!

Comment: Eu tenho outra duvida. quando termina volta pra 10 porque em  contador.innerHTML ta em 10, mas eu queria saber se tem como fazer pro botão 2 voltar pra 20 sem ter que colocar outro script novamente? É porque vai ter mais de 1 botão e o botão 1 vai ser de 10 segundos, o botão 2 vai ser de 20 e assim segue... Tem como eu mirar o  contador.innerHTML para o valor que vai estar no span?

Comment: é só mudar o valor dentro do span para 20, se é que entendi sua duvida

Comment: pera ai, acho que entendi agora vou tentar aqui

Comment: ok, agradeço infinitamente por esta me ajudando!

Comment: Pra simplificar, depois que chega a 0 a contagem volta pro valor definido em contador.innerHTML. E como vai ter mais de um botão com valores diferentes eu queria que a contagem votasse para seus respectivos valores → botão1 vai ser de 10 segundos então ele volta pra 10, botão 2 vai ser de 20 segundos então ele volta pra 20

Comment: Demorei aqui mas consegui hehe, tentei de varias formas para evitar repetir codigo, com array nao deu certo entao, eu adicionei um atributo a mais no contador:
`<input type="button" value="botao1" onclick="dispara('s1')" id="s1" class="btn">
<span class="s1" value="5">5</span>`
Ai  em vez de quando ele zerar ele receber direto o 10, ele recebe :
   contador.innerHTML = contador.getAttribute("value");

Comment: Ai ele volta para o numero que esta no value...

Comment: Você simplesmente é o cara! Não tem noção do quanto me ajudou, sou muito grato a ti cara! Me livrou de muito trabalho!

Comment: Obrigado :) Que bom que consegui te ajudar